# WMI access on a remote server (different domain)

Tags: wmi, mysql-workbench, wmic

I have been trying to make MySQL Workbench's Remote Server Administration to work with my WMI service installed on a Windows 2008 R2 server.

I would like to know if the following syntax is correct and sufficient in order to check if WMI access has been enabled on the server.

wmic /node:myserver.com /user:wmi_user /password:123456 systemenclosure get serialnumber

I have tried the above command from my home laptop however it gives "The RPC server is unavailable" error.

What I have done so far on the server:

- User Account with WMI Rights

Created a separate user account for WMI access(user: wmi_user and it is a member of administrator group).

- Enabled WMI traffic on the firewall using the following command:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="windows management instrumentation (wmi)" new enable=yes

netsh firewall set service RemoteAdmin enable
```

- CIMOM settings

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WBEM\CIMOM\AllowAnonymousCallback change the value from 0 to 1.

- UAC settings

I have adjusted the UAC for wmi_user to never notify.

- DCOM settings

I've read on one article which mentions if the user is in the administrator group, there is no need to change this setting.

Please let me know if there's anything else I missed out. Thank you.